# Netbook doesn't boot after ram replacement

Tags: boot, memory

I have a Samsung NC110 (NP-NC110-A03UK) and have tried to upgrade the memory (4gb to 8gb). After inserting the new RAM, the screen remains black after pressing the 'on' button. The fan and CPU turn on and after a few seconds the hard drive whirs on then stops instantly.
Here are the things that I have tried to do to fix the problem:

- Booting with blank hard drive and no hard drive
- Connecting the 'RTC RESET' jumpers/pins for over 30 seconds with power and battery disconnected (many times)
- Disconnecting power and battery, and holding power button for a minute
- Connecting the netbook to an external display

I know similar questions have been asked previously, but all of the answers do not work and/or do not apply.

- What could cause this?
- Is there a way to fix it?

Edit: This has now been solved, thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: is that the *exact* model number? Google tells me it will only take 2GB RAM - http://www.samsung.com/us/support/faq/FAQ00032169/69610/NP-N135-KA01US

Comment: Sorry, maybe it was from 2gb to 4gb but not sure - my dad was doing it, model number is NP-NC110-A03UK

Comment: then that link has your answer - 2GB is the most it will take.

Comment: So when you put the old RAM back in, does it work as expected or not?

Comment: The link only applies to N models not NC - it says that the netbooks only accept DDR2 while in the netbook it clearly says 'DDR-3 ONLY'

Comment: To answer Techie007, no it doesn't

Comment: @adamantium - Please verify the specifics of the problem and update the question.  You don't have to indicate if the problem has been solved since you accepting an answer indicates that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe @Tetsujin is correct in saying that it only support 2GB, this is/was standard fare for Netbooks.

And that may simply be why it wasn't booting up after the upgrade originally.

If it still doesn't work when you reinsert the old RAM back in, then you/your dad have most likely bunged something up while disassembling it/prodding around inside, as inserting a proper, yet unsupported RAM module won't cause a system to permanently break in the way you're describing.

Check and reset all internal cables and connections, if that doesn't help, then my guess is you've permanently damaged the motherboard while attempting to make it work.

Comment: Had a quick look and found a spare 1gb stick as my dad is out so I don't know where his 2gb is, and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

My daughter was looking for a netbook, so I resurrected my old Samsung NC110 and  upgraded it from 2G to 4G RAM. It recognized the RAM, but booting did not go on automatic. I had to press ENTER several times for it to continue to boot into Win7-32 bit. Then it downloaded tons of updates(about 200+ updates), restarted and booting was smooth again. But only 3.2 G of RAM was usable by the OS. The increase of 1.2G of RAM was worth it for the noticeable improvement in performance.